# How do I use a subdomain with host-gateway in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I want to access http://localhost from inside a docker container, I can add this to my docker-compose file:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Then I can call http://host.docker.internal from inside the container and hit my local server.

How do I call http://subdomain.localhost from inside my container?

I tried this in my docker-compose file, but I get an error

```
extra_hosts:
  - "subdomain.host.docker.internal:subdomain.host-gateway"
```

```
docker-compose run --service-ports main
Error response from daemon: invalid IP address in add-host: "subdomain.host-gateway"
```

I'm hoping there is a solution that doesn't involve extra tools (like using nginx to redirect traffic on the host)

Comment: Where is `subdomain.localhost` defined when you use it from the host and what is it pointing at?

Comment: @HansKilian It's a rails server that operates the same server as localhost. `dig subdomain.localhost` returns `subdomain.localhost. 0 IN A 127.0.0.1`

Comment: Then having `- "subdomain.host.docker.internal:host-gateway"` under `extra_hosts` should work (only have 'subdomain' once).